# Difference beteen using an external Hard Drive Disk Docking Station vs USB to SATA cable

Tags: laptop, usb, external-hard-drive, sata

I have a SATA hard disk that I want to connect to my laptop externally.

Seems like I have two options. One is to buy a [docking station](http://www.ebay.com/itm/US-Plug-IDE-SATA-2-5-3-5-USB-2-0-Dual-HDD-Hard-Drive-Disk-Docking-Station-OTB-/190998501654?pt=US_Drive_Enclosures_Docks&hash=item2c7865d916) and the other is to buy a [cable](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000YJBL78) only. What I would like to know is what are the advantages/disadvantages of one over the other?

What would you recommend in which situations?

Comment: Personally I'd buy a caddy just for the protection while I'm using the drive. Apart from that, I don't think there's much of a difference between the 2. They both connect via USB. They both allow the computer to read the drive. They may differ in the way they work, but to you, it will seem the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conceptually, there is not an aweful lot of difference between the 2 solutions in the general solution.   The cable is probably more a tool for data recovery (as it has IDE and SATA connectors), but they will both perform in a similar manner.

I do note that the docking station you linked to will far outperform the cable you linked to- but not because its a docking station - rather because its a USB3 device as opposed to the cable which is USB2 - and USB provides way faster transfer speeds.   (and don't forget its red, so it must go faster :>  !!! )   Of-course, you get SATA2 docking stations (I'm sure) and SATA3 cables.